# Change value of select option from Python Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

When I inspect a page, I will get these HTML element:

```
<select name="limit">
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Fetch"/>
```

I have a Python Selenium script, which selects the third option, here is the code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="news_info-filter"]/label[5]/select').send_keys('100')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="news_info-filter"]/input[1]').click()
```

But, I wanted to change the value of the third option before clicking the **Fetch** button like this:

```
....
    <option value="2000">100</option>
....
```

What can I try to get to a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the attribute value like this :

```
element =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value = '100']");
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'new value here')", element);
```

and then you can fire up the click on **Fetch** button.